# iOS: How to use Settings/Developer/Logging

Tags: ios, logging, settings

Wondering why I can't find much of anything on this:  On my iPhone and iPad, both of which are running iOS 4.3.x -- and which I'm using for app development -- I see an option under Settings called "Development" and a switch to turn "Logging" on and off.  It has the word "Power" above the field, to add even more of the flavor of mystery to the mix.  Does anyone know what this does?  I would assume that it toggles logging for some function but I've found no way to actually *view* said logs.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

BTW:  I do have an app called "ConsoleLog" on my iPhone (to log app console output) but it works whether the above-mentioned facility is turned on or off.

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually this option Developer->Logging under Settings app on iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch has nothing to do with your application source code log statements but as the header "power" suggests, you can turn this Logging option ON and OFF to know the power consumption of your iOS application on your device when the device is not connected to your development box.

For more details, refer to ["Energy Diagnostics Instruments"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-energy-diagnostics-instruments-help/ConfiguringDisplayOptionsfortheEnergyDiagnosticInstruments/ConfiguringDisplayOptionsfortheEnergyUsageInstrument.html) section.

Also see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8737918/451475).

Comment: Great! Not what I hoped for but useful nonetheless -- thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instruments->File->Import Logged Data from Device.
Good luck!