# Is there a way to accurately measure the impact of "Bluetooth state preservation" on an app energy usage?

Tags: ios, logging, bluetooth, instruments, ble-state-preservation

I would like to monitor the energy usage granularly and measure the impact of [Bluetooth State preservation and restoration for background processing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html)  in iOS.

I'd like to **measure the impact of iOS keeping "the" connection active** to a Bluetooth device even if the app is not running.

Is there a way to do so?

---

**Additional Info**:

I have started recording energy usage for an app a week ago. Now that I imported the logs in Instruments there are none. Is this a hard limit of Xcode Instruments?

**Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737612/energy-usage-instruments-ios) on energy usage logging**:

There is also this question explaining more on the energy usage logging via Instruments. It highlights the limit of the unit of measure (20/20). I think this is a hard limit due to the difficulty on measuring the **relative cell voltage** of the phone battery. Apple probably implemented some **approximation** based on historic usage statistics.